# Woocommerce 3 Filter Single Variation Add to cart button html

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce 3.0 the single variation add to cart button is wrapped in a container div:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
// do_actions for before and after add_to_cart_quantity
</div>
```

I'd like to filter the html to remove the container div without overriding the variation-add-to-cart-button.php template file and without jquery/javascript.

Any help would be great!

Comment: could you please show me screen shot of that page you want?

Comment: *"..without overriding the variation-add-to-cart-button.php template file"* -- May I ask why?

Comment: Hi George - curiosity really. I've made a few sites where I've overridden template files and get annoyed at having to check and update these when woocommerce updates its template files/version numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code. I haven't tested it but it supposed to work. Please try this on your dev environment first.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_template_part', function( $template_name ) {
    if ( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php' === $template_name ) {
        ob_start();
    }
} );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_template_part', function( $template_name ) {
    if ( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php' === $template_name ) {
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        $content = str_replace( '<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">', '', $content );
        $content = str_replace( '</div>', '', $content );
        echo $content;
    }
} );
```